# Simple List<String> contents in JSF 1.2 will not be shown

Tags: jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I have a simple class (the) which contains a

```
List<String> whatEver;
```

plus the appropriate getter/setter.

In JSF i wan't to display this information via ice:DataTable componnet like this:

```
<ice:dataTable id="XXX" var="item" value="#{the.whatEver}" style="empty-cells: show;">
  <f:facet name="header">
      <ice:outputText value="XYZ:"/>
  </f:facet>
  <ice:outputText value="#{item}" />
</ice:dataTable>
```

but it will not show the values via the item. Just the header "XYZ:" but not the values?

Answer (score 0):

After fighting i found the solution which is really simple:

After surrounding it with the ice:column tags it works as expected.

```
<ice:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <ice:outputText value="Kontonummer:"/>
  </f:facet>
  <ice:outputText value="#{konto}" />
</ice:column>
```